# Expo: "auth/operation-not-supported-in-this-enviroment"

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

I develop a react-native (expo) mobile app and try to sign in with a google account to firebase, but I get an error:

> "auth/operation-not-supported-in-this-enviroment. This operation is not supported in the enviroment this application is running on. "location.protocol" must be http, https or chrome-extension and web storage must be enabled"

Code:

```
loginGoogle() {
    var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    provider.addScope('profile');
    provider.addScope('email');
    firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
        var token = result.credential.accessToken;
        var user = result.user;
        return true;
    }).catch(function(error) {
        alert(error.code + '\n' +
        error.message + '\n' +
        error.email + '\n' +
        error.credential);
        return false;
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you using the right `firebase` package?

Comment: @Colin I import firebase just like ‘firebase’ not like ‘react-native-firebase’. I don’t know why, but my expo doesn’t support native firebase lib.

Comment: Well there you go. I'd suggest just using regular `react-native init`.

Comment: @Colin, I will try, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`signInWithPopup` is not supported in react-native. You will need to use a third party OAuth library to get the OAuth ID token or access token and then sign in with Firebase:

```
const cred = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(googleIdToken, googleAccessToken);
firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(cred)
  .then((result) => {
    // User signed in.
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // Error occurred.
  });
```

Comment: Could you please tell me what exactly googleIdToken and googleAccessToken here ?

Comment: These are the Google OAuth ID token and access token which you should get back using a third party OAuth library for react-native.

Answer (score 2):

Firebase does not support `signInWithPopup` in a React Native environment.

You can view a full list of supported environments on [this page](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/environments_js-sdk#other_environments).

You can also submit a feature request for extended Firebase support for React Native [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/features).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **expo bare workflow** or **simple React native cli** (or in simple words which contain android and ios folder) then simply use "React Native Firebase" library.
Here is the link https://rnfirebase.io/

But if you are using **expo managed workflow**(which donot contain android and ios folder ) then you have to follow below steps .

**1.setup google developer account**

use this guide to setup : https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/google/

Note that: use host.exp.exponent  as the package name.

Another problem you may face in this step is generation of hash,which I also faced,the reason for that error is java dev kit(JDK) is not install ,so do install it before proceeding to this step.

**2.Setup Firebase account**

Simply setup firebase project as you set before, enable google sign in service
but this time the only change is you have to add **client ID** of your google developer account in (safest client id field) which will popup once you click on edit **Google signin** in firebase
[look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hcHd.png)

**3.Coding Part**

import * as Google from 'expo-google-app-auth';  //imported from expo package

import {
GoogleAuthProvider,getAuth
} from 'firebase/auth';
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";

import { firebaseconfig } from '[your firebase credentials]';

const app=intitializeApp(firebaseconfig)
const auth=getAuth(app);

async function signInWithGoogleAsync() {

```
try {
    const result = await Google.logInAsync({
        androidClientId: 'cliend id from google dev console',
        iosClientId: 'client id from google dev console for ios app(if you setup)',
        scopes: ['profile', 'email'],
    });

    if (result.type === 'success') {
        console.log(result)
        const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(result.idToken, result.accessToken);

        // Sign in with credential from the Facebook user.
        signInWithCredential(auth, credential)
            .then(async result => {
                console.log(result)
            })
            .catch(error => { console.log(error) });


        return result.accessToken;
    } else {
        console.log("cancelled by user")
        return { cancelled: true };
    }
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    return { error: true };
}//
```

}