# This operation is not supported in the environment this application is runnung on

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

I create react native app with firebase user auth using, here i try to redirect user to login with facebook:

```
login(){
  const provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();

  firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider)
  .then(function(result){
    Alert.alert(result.user.email);
  });
}
```

but i'm getting this error each time:
**This operation is not supported in the environment this application is runnung on."location.protocol" must be http, https or chrome-extension and web storage must be enabled.**
I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44681352/web-google-authentication-with-firebase) question on this forum it's not exactly my problem but i think it's similar.
In my application i use expo, how can i configure expo server or how can i solve it ?

Comment: Did you initialize the project with [`firebase.initializeApp({})`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/learn-more#config-files-objects)?

Comment: @JuanMarco yes I did.

Comment: Are you running this app on a server? Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45059919/javascript-and-firebase-error-this-operation-is-not-supported-in-the-environmen) for details.

Comment: @JuanMarco no, it didn't work :(

Comment: There's no way for the Firebase SDK to show a popup in a React Native app. You'll have to use one of the other sign-in mechanisms. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49966086/expo-auth-operation-not-supported-in-this-enviroment

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen yeah, I've seen that but it have been answered year ago, thank you